# How to recover lost git commits from a few weeks ago?

Tags: git

I am trying to recover changes that were made to a file using git.

I used `reset --hard` on my branch which lost a bunch of commits, and these commits contained changes to a text file.

I understand there are functions like `reflog` in git that can be used to get the hash of commits you thought were lost. In my case, the commits I am trying to recover were from about 3 weeks ago so I am worried that I won't be able to get them back.

Is it possible for me to somehow recover the changes that were made to this file?

Comment: My only bet would be to check each orphaned commit that might match commits you made 3 weels ago. I.e. check date, parent commits, and diffs. Do a checkout to see if they can still be extracted properly.

Comment: from 3 weeks ago, it should be in reflog. Is that not the case? Once you see the commit you care about in the reflog, you can do a checkout or place a branch on it and do a checkout... or actually, anything you like.... to git they are all just commits, which is what it works with, nothing special about them.

Comment: @eftshift0 how can I check the dates of each commit in reflog? is there any way to check the dates systematically across the reflog entries?

Comment: You could try with a little bash-fu: `i=1; while [ $i -lt 100 ]; do echo stash@{$i}; git show --summary --pretty=%cd stash@{$i}; echo; i=$(( $i + 1 )); done`. Feel free to adjust to more or less items in reflog.

Comment: @eftshift0 `git reflog` accepts `log` options: `git reflog --date=short --format="%h %cd %s"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. `git reflog --pretty=oneline --date=short --before=2022-01-09`

   - `--pretty=oneline --date=short` will add the date to the output and it should make it easier to look through the output
   - `--before` should make it easier to only look through relevant days
2. Find the entry that looks like it could have your lost work
3. `git checkout -b my_lost_work` (or `git switch -c my_lost_work`) - create a branch with lost work
4. `git push`

Comment: If the OP knows the branch on which this former commit was done, he can also filter using `git reflog <branch name>`